# Unable to display the selected table in parent page after binding data from popup to parent page

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a sample angular app using angular material.I have taken popup in the TableComponent where I have implemented two tables.

I have a list of data in my first table and my second table is empty.I have implemented swapping data rows functionality between the two tables.

After when I select the required rows form the first table and transfer to second table and when I click on **Save Button**, I am able to fetch the selected data rows in my **saveToParentpage()** function and able to subscribe the selected row data to POPUP declared in my Table Component.

But when I am trying to display the transferred rows in parent page data table , I am not getting any data in my material table created in parent page.

My table in parent page is still empty....!

Please access my [sample app here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-jupiyn?file=app%2Ftable.component.ts)

Can anybody please help me out with this issue....?

Comment: Could you add some code?

Comment: I have added the stackblitz link for sample app here........

Comment: your code is so mash up heena can you please tell with line you use for main table  datastore

Comment: Heena is done now  its working i will show you , you can tell me is you link something this

Comment: In my TableComponent I have first taken the data table for my parent page where initially it is empty..

Comment: I my popup component I have taken two tables where I am swapping the data from first table to second table ..

Comment: then from my second table when I am clicking on save button I need that swapped data rows to be displayed in my parent page

Comment: Heena please  check those images  and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182484/discussion-between-heena-and-harkesh-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Select record from main table and move to first**

[image]

**After  Click save record show in main table**

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-c3mxvq?file=app/popup.html